# NTP config настройки ntpd

Tags: c++, linux

Добрый день!

1. Пишу программу на с++, которая настраивает демон ntpd. Что прописать в файле ntp.conf, чтобы замкнуть сервер времени на самого себя, т.е. синхронизироваться с самим собой? (Писал `server 127.0.0.1 и server 192.168.5.4 (мой IP в локалке). Ответ: usnychronised time server re-starting.)
2. Можно ли (и нужно?) указывать маску, если мы соединяемся с сервером времени. (server 192.168.5.4 **mask 255.255.255.0** (возможны такие ситуации, что нужно писать маску, или это **вообще недопустимо**?)).
3. Как сделать, чтобы соседние компьютеры в локальной сети могли брать у меня время? Читал где-то, люди пишут restrict 192.168.1.0, но мне не помогло.

**Обновление**

1. Время не отличается вообще, я хочу замкнуться на себя (я сервер) и не давать время никому. Т.е. чтобы моё локальное время и было эталонным для меня самого. (Отключить ntpв мне не подходит.) Что нужно написать?
2. Таблица маршрутизации - restrict вы имеете ввиду? Видел, что пишут restrict 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0
3. Прописать жестко на других компьютерах я могу, но мне надо, чтобы при этом мой компьютер ему это время выдавал.  В общем, в итоге мне нужно две записи настроек: одна, чтобы мой компьютер не давал время никому; и вторая, чтобы он своё (эталонное) время мог раздавать другим.

Comment: Это не вопрос по C++.

Answer (score 1):

1. Если время на сервере и на машине сильно отличается, они не синхронизируются. Проверьте, какое время выдает ваш сервис. Попробуйте синхронизировать другой компьютер, будет ли ошибка.
2. Нет, маска нужна только для таблиц маршрутизации. Вам нужно указывать только ip-адрес (или хост).
3. На них можно настроить синхронизацию с вашим сервером напрямую, указав ip. Можете также почитать про DHCP+NTP, чтобы компьютеры в вашей сети могли автоматически подключаться к нужному сервису синхронизации.

Comment: Обновил вопрос